# docker-compose and ssh volumes

Tags: docker, docker-compose, macos-sierra

I am starting to use Docker and specifically `docker-compose`. When building the container and it's services I would like to be able to use the hosts SSH keys so that I can pull from some private repo's. I am trying to add a volume like below but this does not seem to be working

```
version: "2.0"
  services:
  my-service:
    build:
      context: .
    args:
      arg_1: arg1
      arg_2: arg2
    volumes:
      - ~/.ssh:/root/.ssh
```

When cloning a repo i get the error

```
ssh_askpass: exec(/usr/bin/ssh-askpass): No such file or directory
```

And when logging into the container the keys are not there. Am i approaching this incorrectly ?

Thanks

Comment: Have you try to write the complete local path and not with ~/.ssh?

Comment: Post the contents of your Dockerfile

Answer (score 0):

Which operating system do you use? Be aware that on some systems there is additional virtualization layer and the path ~/.ssh can refer to that virtual machine.

For example on Windows 7 you can manage these machines by docker-machine command.

Comment: As far as I know Mac uses virtual machines as docker host. The directory you mounted by volumes is in fact directory on that virtual machine not your host.